# scandir returns [0] =>. and [1]=>.. in array

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP script with this snippet of code:

```
$files  = scandir($dir);    
print_r($files);
```

And noticed in my array i have:

```
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => assets.php
    [3] => loader.php
```

Is this a bug on my server or is it expected behavior, what are they? And if it's the latter is there any way to exclude them from the scan? As I wish to only get script files that I made from the directory and nothing else. Is there any way to exclude them from the scan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it isn't a bug.... `.` is the current directory, `..` the parent directory

See the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

The user-contributed notes show one way of excluding them:

```
$directory = '/path/to/my/directory';
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
```

If you use other options besides scandir, such as SPL's DirectoryIterator, there's options to exclude them (such as combining it with a RegexIterator), or to test for them as you're iterating:

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem :) Are there beneficial reasons to use SPL to scandir?

Comment: This is common on *NIX operating system, and designed for relative folder browsing (like you use for css/img : `src="../img/myimg.png"`)

Comment: @Blag - Not simply *nix, it's always existed in Windows too, and DOS before that

Comment: @Dave - SPL is a bit more complex to understand, but it allows you to do much more complex filtering, and recursive folder searching; and it's OOP if that matters

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, just saw for DOS & W$, make sense for the console browsing.